# Limit included file options

Tags: php, include, limit, require

i working now on template engine right now and i faced a problem that i think i might not find solution by my self.

As part of the template engine i need to include PHP files. how can i limit that PHP file i have import that he wont be able to run function from specific file of the core system?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to include/require variable files. You will be susceptible to arbitrary code injection (code running on your webserver). Try to design your template engine differently.

Comment: what you you want to limit ... the number of files you want to include or the content of the file ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how effective this would be, but you could give the file that renders everything it's own namespace, different to the core files.

It wouldn't stop it 100%, but it would force them to look up the core namespaces etc, and it might stop general tapping of functions for those who are not so into delving into the core files.